# Flask RuntimeError: working outside of application context

Tags: python, flask, callback

I want to run my Flask app with websocket. Everything seems to be ok as long as I am starting my joiner class (running as thread) and then want to register a call back funktion. This works ok with flask development server. 
As I am not very good in Englisch I have problems to understand the context issues with Flask. Any help would be very much appreciated

```
@socketio.on('change_R8', namespace='/fl')
def change_Relay8(R8_stat):
    if R8_stat == 'on':
        #print("Relay 8 on")
        ui.set_relay(8,1,0)
    elif R8_stat == 'off':
        #print("Relay 8 off")
        ui.set_relay(8,0,0) 

# Listen for SocketIO event that will change analog output

@socketio.on('change_ao', namespace='/fl')
def change_ao(ao_value):
    #print("setze ao auf: ", ao_value)
    ui.set_ao(ao_value)         

#- call back function from UniPi_joiner_class----------------------------

def unipi_change(event, data):
    #print("Webserver in: ",event,data)
    emit_to_all_clients(event, data)

# main program ----------------------------------------------------------    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log.text("Flask Web-Server gestartet")
    print("Flask Web-Server gestartet")
    joiner = unipi_joiner("10.0.0.52",0)
    joiner.on_unipi_change(unipi_change)
    socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', use_reloader=False, debug=False)
    log.text("Flask Web-Server beendet")
```

Comment: Please include the complete stack trace of the error that you are getting. It would also be useful if you explain what the `unipi_joiner()` function does.

Answer (score 0):

The joiner function delivers data from sensors in the format event, data(json) which I emit to my website with broadcast. The data comes from 2 different sources (time dependend) and are joined together in the joiner function using queues. This works ok with Flask development server. When I use eventlet then  joiner.on_unipi_change(unipi_change) does not work and shows context error. I tested the server with data from within flask and it worked.

Question: would it be possible to deliver the sensor data through websocket to my Flask server and then from flask server to my web-site. This would be very interesting as I would have different Raspi 3 collecting data and sending it to my web server.

Regarding complete stack trace I need some guidelines (sorry Flask beginner)